# Discord has no attribute named 'StoreChannel'

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot that returns the most popular videos in the KR region regarding a topic which actually is the message of the user.

So far i coded import discord

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
from discord.ext import commands
import typing
from discord_ui import UI
cmd = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
client = discord.Client()

token = 


api_service_name = "youtube"
api_version = "v3"
DEVELOPER_KEY = 'googleapikeyhere'
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    api_service_name, api_version, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

@cmd.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.reply(f"You are on cooldown for {round(error.retry_after, 2)} seconds!")


@ cmd.command()
@ commands.cooldown(1, 4, commands.BucketType.user)
async def info(ctx, *args):
    output2 = ''
    for word in args:
        output2 += str(word)
        output2 += ' '
        print(output2)
    request3 = youtube.videos().list(
        part="snippet, {}, statistics".format(output2),
        chart="mostPopular",
        regionCode="KR"
    )
    response3 = request3.execute()
    print(response3)
    channame = response3['items'][0]['snippet']['title']
    chanid = response3['etag']
    numberViews = response3['Items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount']
    numberLikes = response3['Items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount']
    embed2 = discord.Embed(title=f"{channame}", url=f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={chanid}",
                         numberviews=f"{numberViews}", numberlikes= f"{numberLikes}", color=0xFF5733)
    response3 = request3.execute()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed2)

cmd.run('findvideos')
```

but it results in the error discord has no attribute 'StoreData' why is that ?

Comment: Hello. For helping you it is necessary to see a meaningfull traceback - where does the error happen.

Comment: hello i finally solved it by adding "intents=discord.Intents.all()" to cmd, thanks for answering and deleting the import discord.Ui as my code didnt use it

Comment: Your welcome. Feel free to add your solution as as answer, so others know it is solved.

Comment: On another note, you have both a `Bot` and a `Client`, which doesn't make any sense, and you're using some `discord_ui` package which isn't necessary because UI components are already built-in to discord.py.

Comment: indeed i deleted it. :)